# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment (C)

Tags: c++, c

I see many different answers to this question and have looked at many of them yet I cannot find the answer to my problem.

The error im getting is

```
bitarray.c:27:19: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

(newArr << i) ^= 1;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `newArr = (newArr << i) ^ 1` ? If you clarify what you want, you will probably solve your own problem.

Comment: Answer that so I can checkmark it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to assign to a result from an operation another result. Try the following right way to do it:

```
newArr = (newArr << i) ^ 1;
```

The idea is that you have to have a valid lvvalue and the temporary result of the "<<" is not a valid one. You need a variable like newArr. The following answer on SO explains many terms related to this situation:

[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Hope I shed some light on the problem!

Answer (score 0):

"<<" is a binary operator just like "+" or a "-".
It needs to be assigned to a variable.
For Eg. you cannot just write this 
               a+b;
Correct way is 
               c = a+b;

Comment: You do not need to assign it. You *can* write `a+b`.