# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment, I got this error what is lvalue and rvalue and how to remove this error

Tags: c++, c, linux

I got this error in my code while compiling
here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int l,n,w,h;
    cin>>l>>n;
    while(n--){
        cin>>w>>h;
        if(w>l||h>l)
            cout<<"CROP IT"<<endl;
        if(w==l&&h==l&&w=h)
            cout<<"ACCEPTED"<<endl;
        if(w<l||h<l)
            cout<<"UPLOAD ANOTHER"<<endl;
    }
}
```

and the error

> 11:22: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: This is a repeated question. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973320/error-lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-c

Comment: Using the spacebar would make the cause much easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if(w==l&&h==l&&w=h)` is likely wrong. Because of operator precedence, it is doing `if((w==l&&h==l&&w)=h)`. The `w==l&&h==l&&w` part creates a temporary value. Temporaries are always rvalues, and you can't assign `h` to it.

I suspect you meant to write `if(w==l&&h==l&&w==h)`, but really, what's the point of the last `w==h`? If both `w` and `h` are equal to `l`, then surely `w` is equal to `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of operator precedence, `(w==l && h==l && w=h)` is treated as ((w==l && h==l && w) = h).
The first part is an rvalue, so you cannot assign it to `h`.

You wanted to write for sure `(w==l && h==l && w==h)`.